# DELETE some records from a sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have created in my SQL Data Base a table with only two columns of type `UniqueIdentifier`.
Now I need to delete certain records with the same UserId. And the code is:

```
If aspProvider.SQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then aspProvider.SQLConn.Open()
     QueryString = "DELETE FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles WHERE UserId = @UserNewId"
     dbHandler.SQLComm = New SqlCommand(QueryString, aspProvider.SQLConn)
     srvHandler.SQLComm.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect
     dbHandler.SQLComm.Parameters.Add("@UserNewId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = UsrId
     srvHandler.SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

When the pointer comes to the line `srvHandler.SQLComm.CommandType`, then it throws me an error:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

The same happens when I delete this line, and when the pointer comes to the line:

`srvHandler.SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()`

The `UsrId`is the value of a GUID, and it's there when I debug the code
Is someone to show me where I do something wrong? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `dbHandler` instead of `srvHandler`?

Comment: This is just a Namespace but finally has something to do with the all problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by changing the code:

```
If aspProvider.SQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then aspProvider.SQLConn.Open()
  QueryString = "DELETE FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles WHERE UserId = @UserNewId"
  Using SQLComm As New SqlCommand(QueryString, aspProvider.SQLConn)
  SQLComm.Parameters.Add("@UserNewId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = UsrId
  SQLComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using
```